# Identify sheet number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with sheets having names: Student (1), Student (2), Student (3) and so on.

I am adding a sheet through vba with will be named Student (4) if there are three sheets already present. How can I identify the last sheet number (3 in this case) so I know I need to name the next sheet Student (4)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below displays the largest current student number.  Is this what you were after?

Warning.  In my experience workbooks become very difficult to use as the number of worksheets increases.  I have used one with 40 sheets and found it a nightmare.  There is also a theoretical limit of 255 although I told Excel will exceed other limits before it can be reached.

```
Option Explicit
Sub NextSheetName()

  Dim NameCrnt As String
  Dim NumCrnt As Long
  Dim NumMax As Long
  Dim Pos As Long
  Dim WkSht As Worksheet

  NumMax = 0

  For Each WkSht In Worksheets
    NameCrnt = WkSht.Name
    Pos = InStr(1, NameCrnt, "(")
    If Pos = 0 Then
      ' Code to handle non-standard name.
    Else
      NumCrnt = Val(Mid(NameCrnt, Pos + 1, 1))
      If NumMax < NumCrnt Then
        NumMax = NumCrnt
      End If
    End If
  Next

  Debug.Print "Largest current student number=" & NumMax

End Sub
```